# How Can I Recursively Compare Azure Resource Groups?

Tags: azure

I have one resource group that I set up with the portal and another that I tried to configure the same way using Terraform.

Each group contains

- Application Gateway with Web App Firewall
- Virtual networks and subnets
- VMs and associated storage
- Public IPs, NSGs, NIC etc

Is there a way for me to compare the two sets of configurations?

Comment: Any more update for the question? Please let me know if it's helpful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you, I assume you want to create the same resources with the same configurations in another group through Terraform. On my side, there are not many things you need to care about. Just according to the configuration of the resources to create the terraform script.

1. each resource region
2. the public IP and the NIC allocation method
3. NSG rules
4. vnet and the subnet address prefix
5. application gateway properties and the rules

The above points are that I think you need to care about. And the properties of the resources in Terraform also need to according to. I think there is no other way to compare two sets of configurations. If you really want, you can compare the template of each group when you create them. The group template shows below:

[image]

Comment: @opticyclic You can export each resources template through the Azure CLI command [`az group deployment export`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-export). And you get the deployment names through the list command.

Answer (score 0):

No, i dont think there is a reasonable straight forward way of doing this, you can create a powershell script that would get resources in each resource group and then try and compare properties, but its hard to give some sort of estimation how accurate it would be, there is a `Compare-Object` cmdlet in powershell, which might help you with that.